# Помогите, пожалуйста, как сделать так чтобы в Python из библиотеки tkinter было поле для ввода (где отображается число) сделать больше?

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
def roll ():
    text.delete(0.0, END)
    text.insert (END, str (randint(1, 9)))
root = Tk()
text = Text(root, width = 36, height = 10)
buttonA = Button(root, text = 'Press to roll!', command = roll)
text.pack()
buttonA.pack()
```

[image: в окне tk]

Comment: увеличить width = 36, height = 10 не поможет ?

Comment: это величина окна tk, а мне надо поле там где будет отображться случайное число

Comment: нет,это величина текстового поля. величина окна пишется иначе-вон ниже ответили.

Comment: добавлю важный момент немного в стороне. window лучше не называть-окон бывает много. по традиции основное окно называют root

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию размер (ширина и высота) определяется совокупностью размеров расположенных в нем виджетов. В случае если окно пустое, то tkinter устанавливает его размер в 200 на 200 пикселей.

С помощью метода geometry() можно изменить как размер окна, так и его положение. Метод принимает строку определенного формата.Попробуйте данный способ :

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x400+200+100')
root.mainloop()
```

Оригинал [здесь](https://younglinux.info/tkinter/window)

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но у меня кнопка пропала

Comment: в вашем коде используется окно а не корень. buttonA = Button(window замените на buttonA = Button(root

Comment: я уже поменял на root

Comment: тогда исправьте код на новый

Comment: root.geometry('1200x900+0+0')

Comment: В конструкторе Текст(width и height) уменьшите.

Comment: пробовал все, и не выходит

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

def roll():
    text.delete(0.0, END)
    text.insert (END, str (randint(1, 9)))
    text.tag_add('title', 0.0, 'end')
    text.tag_config('title', font=("Verdana", 34, 'bold'), justify=CENTER)

root = Tk()

text = Text(root) 
text.pack()
buttonA = Button(root, text = 'Press to roll!', command = roll)
buttonA.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное!)

Comment: @Nodwidch  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour